# PHP Special char \t treated as string

Tags: php, database, string, special-characters

I'm getting delimiter for data file from db and save it to some `$delimiter` var and pass it to class of file reader.

`new CSVreader($delimiter);`

And the problem is that it dont treat it as tabulator, but as `backslash + t letter` string.

When I'm passing this directly like: `new CSVreader("\t");` instead it works ok

so final question is: How to convert `\t` string from `database` to be treated as `special char (tab)`

I'm using `UTF-8` for db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace `\t` by a tabulator character using `str_replace`:

```
$text = str_replace('\t', "\t", $text);
```

If you have more escape sequences, not just `\t`, `str_replace` permits specifying the replacement in arrays:

```
$text = str_replace(array('\t','\n','\r','\f','\b','\a','\e','\\\\'),
                    array("\t","\n","\r","\f","\010","\007","\033","\\"), $text);
```

Ah, here's the complete list of escape sequences allowed in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

I should mention that `str_replace` does not do the replacement correctly; it is equivalent to doing a replacement of each pair in sequence. This means that something like `\\t` is expanded either into a tab or backslash preceding a tab depending on the order, not into `\t`. This issue is solved by using `strtr`:

```
$text = strtr($text, array('\t'=>"\t",'\n'=>"\n",'\r'=>"\r",'\f'=>"\f",
                      '\b'=>"\010",'\a'=>"\007",'\e'=>"\033",'\\\\'=>"\\"));
```

Another function you could use is [`stripcslashes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php). It implements also the octal and hex escape codes, which you may or may not want.

Comment: Can you supply some more universal way for all the special chars etc.

Comment: Universal? There is no universally agreed definition of what escape sequences there are.

Comment: See the update for some common ones. As you can see, some of them don't exist in PHP (backspace, bell, escape)

Answer (score 2):

PHP interpreter automatically escapes double quoted strings found in PHP source files, so `new CSVreader("\t")` actually indicates a TAB character.

On the contrary, when you read a string from any external source, the backslash assumes its literal value: a backslash and a 't'. You would express it in a PHP source as `"\\t"` (double quotes) or `'\t'` (single quotes), which is not what you want.

Anyway, PHP provides a native function for that. [stripcslashes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php) recognises C-like sequences (\a, \b, \f, \n, \r, \t and \v), as well as octal and hexadecimal representation, converting them to their actual meaning.

```
// C-like escape sequence
stripcslashes('\t') === "\t"; // true;

// Hexadecimal escape sequence
stripcslashes('\x09') === "\t"; // true;

// Octal escape sequence
stripcslashes('\011') === "\t"; // true;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well when you are retrieving the seperator character from a database which might be a special character not just , ; etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

You can expand the array with more special characters, if you want.

```
function myFunc($string) {
  $search  = array('\t', '\n', '\r'); //you can add more special chars here
  $replace = array( "\t",  "\n",  "\r");
  return str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}
```

Or, if you prefer one-liners:

```
echo str_replace('\t', "\t", $string);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) & [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) for exact replaces. But if you want your string to be interpreted like c strings, you can use [`stripcslashes()`](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php), but you should use it with care, as it unquotes octal & hexadecimal representations too (f.ex. this `stripcslashes('\\0')` becomes the null character).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways.

```
<?php
function trans($string) {
    return strtr($string, array(
        '\t'    => "\t",
        '\r'    => "\r",
        '\n'    => "\n"
    ));
}

$string = 'Hello\tAnthony';

echo $string;                               //Hello\tAnthony
echo str_replace('\t', chr(9), $string);    //Hello Anthony
echo trans($string);                        //Hello Anthony
```